# Sql Query How to select a certain data and output the rest of the result

Tags: mysql, sql, select, where-clause

This is my table

```
ID     Name
1      ddd
2      bbb
3      ccc
4      aaa
5      eee
```

Is it possible to make a query that will select a data that starts with a certain letter and get all the rest that follows it and leave the rest that comes before it?
Alphabetically.

What is the query if i want to select `ccc, ddd, eee`

The result should be something like this..

```
ID    Name
3     ccc
1     ddd
5     eee
```

Comment: @user3167278: `ORDER BY` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works: (See the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ada7d2/1))

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE NAME >=
    (SELECT NAME FROM TABLE_NAME
     WHERE NAME LIKE 'c%'
     ORDER BY NAME ASC --to ensure first name is truly the first
     LIMIT 1 --to ensure there's only one value from the subquery
    )
ORDER BY NAME ASC
```

The subquery gets the alphabetically first name matching your first letter requirement. The main query gets all the rows where the name matches or is alphabetically greater than the subquery result.

The `ASC` keyword is superfluous, but I thought I'd make it clear.

The `LIKE` check is case sensitive. If you would like it to be case insensitive, use `UPPER(NAME) LIKE 'C%'` or `LOWER(NAME) LIKE 'c%'`. You should also change the *where* clause of main query to `WHERE UPPER(NAME) >=` or `WHERE LOWER(NAME) >=`.

---

Based on [AjaySingh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20962171/1134080), the following would work better (more efficient), but you're limited to matching only the first letter (more complex `LIKE` patterns still require my query above).

```
SELECT  * FROM table_name WHERE name >= 'c' ORDER BY name
```

See the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ada7d2/5). *Credits to AjaySingh where due.*

Comment: You, sir, are an evil genius.

Comment: Oh you Canadians are so generous with your compliments `^_^`

Comment: This really helps a lot ! tnx ^___^

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT  * FROM @Temp WHERE name > 'c%' ORDER BY name
```

Comment: This sort of works too (and the execution plan is better than mine), except you'll have to change the condition to `>= 'c'` to be more correct. Because (a) the operator `>` does not support `%` pattern matching (b) there could be a row where the value is just 'c'. See [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ada7d2/5).

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE NAME > 'CERTAINLETTER%' ORDER BY NAME
```

You should never use reserved names such as NAME for the field name. Change it to something like fldNAME or something.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I didn't understand the question that well. Edited it already.